# Orchard CMS Showing RSS Feed On Page

Tags: rss, orchardcms

I have a requirement to show an RSS feed from a third party site. I don't want to do this through the browser's RSS mechanism. Instead I want to embed the feed (with styling) into a particular page.

My question is, can this be done just using the CMS admin? Is there a particular content type/part I can use? Or would this have to be done programatically?

I realise there are modules that I could download, but I see no support for RSS feeds for Orchard 1.6, which I'm using. The ones I've tried are for later versions.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

These may be useful if anyone else encounters problems:

http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/401201

http://vandelay.codeplex.com/workitem/23

For the second one, I simply removed the offending class file as I didn't need this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Vandelay.Industries module has an external rss feature. Be sure to get the source code from vandelay.codeplex.com

Comment: Does the Vandelay.Industries external rss feature work with Orchard v.1.10.1.0? I installed and enabled all features, but can't find it anywhere in the admin dashboard.

Comment: Yes, it's been refreshed for 1.10.x, but the source code has been moved to https://github.com/bleroy/vandelay